Dimension bars and arrow positioning in tikz
I am trying to get my dimension lines to work properly, as right now my bar-type dimension lines are all too short by exactly 1/2" linewidth on either end. Take the following results from the mwe, (zoomed in significantly to the left hand point of interest). I need to replicate the change from the green to orange line with the red to blue dimension lines, but I am at a loss for as to how. The goal is to have the blue dimension bar lie directly atop the black line of the rectangle.
Edit:
To clarify, the solution must not involve manually altering the coordinates of the lines in any way, as they are all derived in something not so simple as this MWE. Im looking to redefine the definition of how the bar lines are drawn so I can make a style.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\linewidth/10cm, >=Stealth]
%draw the shape rectangle
\draw (0,-2) rectangle (10, 2);
%draw the normal lines
\draw[color = green] (0,0.12) -- (10,0.12);
\draw[color = orange, cap = rect] (0,0.1) -- (10,0.1);
%draw the dimention lines
\draw[|-|, color = blue] (0,0) -- (10,0);
\draw[<->, color = red] (0,0) -- (10,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


with for example ([xshift=-0.5\pgflinewidth]0,0)

Sorry I should have specified that Im looking for a way to adjust the style of the bar lines without manually adjusting every point. For anything but this MWE its not a feasible solution as everything is run off variables and math.

With this post Option for a custom TikZ command which can be set to one of three values and this TikZ arrow tip is displaced
We can use \draw[{|[sep=0pt -0.5]}-{|[sep=0pt -0.5]},blue]
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  scale=\linewidth/10cm, 
  >=Stealth,
  bar line/.style={%
      |[sep=0pt -0.5]}-{|[sep=0pt -0.5]
    }
  ]
%draw the shape rectangle
\draw (0,-2) rectangle (10, 2);
%draw the normal lines
\draw[color = green] (0,0.12) -- (10,0.12);
\draw[color = orange, cap = rect] (0,0.1) -- (10,0.1);
%draw the dimention lines
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \draw[|-|, color = blue] (0,0) -- (10,0);
\draw[bar line,blue](0,0) -- (10,0);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\draw[<->, color = red] (0,0) -- (10,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thank you for the direction and the links to relevent posts. I have worked out \tikzset{ |-|/.tip  = {Bar[sep=0pt -.5 1]}}
which seems to do what I wanted. Is there a reason why you proposed a .style over a .tip other than that in my edit I ignorantly used the word style?

It's more out of habit, I didn't think to separate the .tip from the .style and I found the second post after my answer.
